# JavaScript, return promise inside arrow function

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I've just seen this code:

```
const buildSW = () => {
  // This will return a Promise <- that comment was present on the code
  workboxBuild
    .injectManifest({
      swSrc: 'src/sw.js'
      // some code
    })
    .then(({ count, size, warnings }) => {
      // some code
    })
    .catch(console.error);
};
buildSW();
```

The code seems to be working, has been in production like 1 year, but I get confused with the comment of `This will return a Promise` because I don't see that there is actually a `return` statement, and the whole code is inside { }.

Shouldn't be?:

```
return workboxBuild
    .injectManifest({ ...etc
```

The code is part from this guides:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/generate-service-worker/workbox-build

where the `return` promise is present there. So how or why is working without return in the code showed above?

Comment: `workboxBuild.injectManifest` will return a promise

Comment: I think you're interpreting the comment as a comment about `buildSW`, but it looks like they're commenting on `workboxBuild.injectManifest`. The code usage also implies this since any return value from `buildSW` is ignored.

Comment: As the caller just does `buildSW()` without treating the return value, it wouldn't make a difference, but yes, it would make more sense if there was the `return` statement.

Comment: That's the part that get me confused, `it would make more sense` so it is wrong, it's ok, or could be both ways?

Comment: @pmiranda ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ returning the promise makes it possible to `await` the function (or use `.then()` but if that's never been needed then...it's OK, I guess.

Comment: @pmiranda We can only guess at the original commenter's intent, both with the code, and the comment. Normally documentation comments about a function go outside the function, e.g., documentation for `buildSW` would be above its implementation. It doesn't look like `buildSW` was intended to return anything, rather to call `injectManifest` and do some stuff with its returned promise, and that's all.

Comment: The code is present in many guides around WITH `return`, I put a link of the original example, here's another one: https://lifesaver.codes/answer/guidlines-for-using-workbox and another from CRA of Facebook (they created the example) https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5673

Comment: In the first link nothing useful is returned, and the code ignores any returned value. The second link is the literal source for the content of the first link; it's just scraped. And they're both just copies of the original source example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get confused with the comment because I don't see that there is actually a `return` statement, like it is present in the guide. Shouldn't it have one?

Yes, there should be a `return` statement. Sure, the function already catches errors and logs them, but it's still a good idea to always return a promise from asynchronous functions.

> So how or why is working without return in the code showed above?

It's working only because the `buildSW();` call you're doing doesn't try to use the promise that should be returned.

Answer (score 2):

The comment is commenting on the line following it, and is redundant. E.g.

```
// a() will return a Promise
a().then(() => () // duh
```

...because it's equivalent to:

```
const promise = a();
promise.then(() => ()
```

> Shouldn't be?: `return workboxBuild.injectManifest({ ...etc`

It depends on the contract you want `buildSW` to have.

As written, `buildSW` returns nothing and handles its own errors, using `.catch(console.error)` to emit them to console. Appropriate for event handlers — E.g. `button.onclick = buildSW`.

But if you expect to call `buildSW` from other places, a better contract is to return a promise, and leave error handling to the caller:

```
const buildSW = () => {
  return workboxBuild.injectManifest({swSrc: 'src/sw.js'})
    .then(({ count, size, warnings }) => {
      // some code that may also fail
    });
};
buildSW().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: "*The comment is commenting on the line following it*" - I disagree. In the google guide where it was copy-pasted from it certainly refers to both the `injectManifest` as well as the `buildSW` method.

Comment: @Bergi well there it made sense (because the next line began with `return`) whereas here it does not. But sure, copy-paste-mistake is another possible answer.